# If there's a way to solve element uniqueness problem in O(n)

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

there any help in such problem??

Comment: At first you should fix you current code. It contains several obvious errors.

Comment: You're getting O(1) behavior because you're *performing exactly one comparison* - `x[0]` to `x[1]`.  Based solely on the result of that comparison, you either return True or False: nothing else in the list gets examined at all.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```py
    def check_elements(arr):
        return len(arr) == len(set(arr))
```

**UPD**
I think I get the point. Given a list with constant length (say 50). And we need to add **such circumstances** to the problem that solving this problem will take O(n) time. And I suppose not like O(n) dummy operations but kinda reasonable O(n).

Well... the only way a see where we can get O(n) are elements themselves. Say we have something like this:

```py
[
1.1111111111111111..<O(n) digits>..1,
1.1111111111111111..<O(n) digits>..2,
1.1111111111111111..<O(n) digits>..3,
1.1111111111111111..<O(n) digits>..1,
]
```

Basically we can treat elements as very long string. And to check whether constant number of n-character strings are unique or not we have to at least read them all. And it's at least O(n) time.

Comment: The first one, but i don't mean the code itself but i mean the general concept behind the algorithm.. How can  run an algorithm of O(1) in O(n)??

Comment: @Harmony what do you mean by O(1) in O(n)? O(1) memory and O(n) time?

Comment: I mean if we have an array that has specific number of elements, it will takes complexity O(1) time to iterate over the elements of array using for-loop.. My question is how can we get complexity O(n) for the same array that has specific size if we used for -loop ?

Comment: When we iterate an array, the time complexity is O(n) where n is the length of the array. How do you get O(1) ? O(1) means that regardless of the length of the array, the processing time is always the same.

Comment: @Harmony well... mathematically for any function f(const) = O(1) where you suppose to get your `n` variable? Oh... may be if elements are REAL numbers with very high precision so then if we assume we have 50 REAL numbers such each in worse case has N bits. We really need O(n) complexity to check if they are all unique.

Comment: Is it possible to solve Element Uniqueness problem in O(n) if we have an array has elements between 1 and 100 ?

Comment: @Harmony integers or real?

Comment: Integer numbers

Comment: @Harmony what is n? When we say f(n) = O(n) that means n is a variable. In your problem there are no variables at all. You have constant list of constant elements. So what is n?

Comment: can you plz explain this line of code works internally or implements internally ..         return len(arr) == len(set(arr))

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a **counting sort**, in your case it will be in O(n). Create an array from 0 to N (N is your maximum value), and then if you have value v in the original array, add one to the value-th entry of the resulting array. This will takes you O(n) (juste review all values from the original array), and then juste search in the resulting array if there is an entry greater than 1...

Comment: If the goal is to return true if all the elements of a vector are unique and it is known that there are only `k` possible values for some constant `k`, then there is a simple O(1) algorithm because only `k` elements need to be examined. If there are more than `k` elements in the vector, then there is a duplicate by the pigeon hole principle; we don't need to examine any element to know that. So from an algorithmic complexity viewpoint, counting search is overkill :-)

Comment: "add one to the value-th entry of the resulting array" can you please give more clarification to this sentnce plz